# From a shapefile, copy specific rows (defined by a separate table) to a new shapefile

Tags: shapefile

I have a polygon shapefile of origin zones.
I also have a polygon shapefile of destination zones.
I also have a table that lists origin-destination pairs.

I would like to create a multi-part shapefile where each row represents an origin-destination pair. So when you select a single row, two separate polygons would be highlighted (one polygon representing the origin zone, the other representing the destination zone).

I don't know how to go about creating the multi-part shapefile. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Which software are you using ?

Comment: How many features are there in the original zones shapefiles?

Answer (score 3):

You need to look into how to create Multi-Polygons in what ever software you are using. If you are planning to do this programatically I can recommend [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) which will provide you with the classes you need to read in the two shapefiles, combine the two polygons into a multipolygon and write the shapefile back out.

Comment: This is true for desktop GIS but I guess/hope it is possible to do it without multi-polygon for webmapping.

Comment: the question asked for a way to write out a multi poly shapefile

Comment: sure, but I was thinking maybe avoiding it (according to his needs)!

Comment: Sure, I'd use a postgis view my self